# What User permission required to upload chatter images?

Tags: chatter, permissions

I am looking for profile permission to upload chatter images for other users.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends" on [how the file is shared](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_uploading.htm&language=en_US) and on what permissions a user already has in your organization. This help page, [File Sharing Settings and Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_settings_perms.htm&language=en_US#collab_files_settings_perms) probably explains it best.

There are three permissions that will allow you to upload files to chatter to share with others. The most basic is [Chatter Internal User](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000176663&language=en_US). Two others are "Deliver Uploaded Files and Personal Content" plus one called "Create and Share Links to Chatter Files". For a more extensive list of permissions, see [What does each permission on a user's profile mean?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000198725&language=en_US)